# Why does GitLab not show merge pipeline anymore in MR?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Until now I had my whole GitLab configuration placed inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`. The configuration looked as follows:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: ...

.deploy-default:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    ...

.rules_mr_or_branch_manual:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual

.rules_mr_or_commit_not_master_not_release:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "release"'
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "master" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != "release"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

.build_default:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    ...

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
  - post-deploy

build-production:
  extends:
    - .build_default
  environment:
    name: production
  interruptible: true
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"'
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "release"'
      allow_failure: false

build-staging:
  extends:
    - .build_default
  environment:
    name: staging
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      allow_failure: false

build-test:
  extends:
    - .build_default
    - .rules_mr_or_commit_not_master_not_release
  environment:
    name: test

# Test jobs
test-unit:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - yarn install && yarn test:unit
  coverage: /All\sfiles.*?\s+(\d+.\d+)/
  artifacts:
    reports:
      cobertura: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "release"'
      allow_failure: false
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

# Deploy jobs
deploy-test:
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
    - .rules_mr_or_branch_manual
  environment:
    name: test
  allow_failure: true

deploy-staging:
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
  environment:
    name: staging
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    variables:
      - $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "pipeline"

deploy-production:
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
  environment:
    name: production
  interruptible: false
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    refs:
      - release
```

Since it is planned to further extend the configuration with more jobs in near future, I thought I need to refactor my config in a way that it will stay readable even if many more jobs are added. For that reason, I split my config into several files, and furthermore, I rewrote my rules. I created a rule set to be able to reuse them in several jobs, and I used workflow to set rules which are applied globally. The result of the refactoring process looks as follows:

---

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: ...

include:
  - local: '/.gitlab/variables.yml'
  - local: '/.gitlab/rules.yml'
  - local: '/.gitlab/workflows.yml'
  - local: '/.gitlab/stages/test.yml'
  - local: '/.gitlab/stages/build.yml'
  - local: '/.gitlab/stages/deploy.yml'

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
```

---

**.gitlab/variables.yml**

```
variables:
  STAGING_BRANCH_NAME: $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME
  PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME: $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME
```

---

**.gitlab/rules.yml**

```
.rule_references:
  pipeline__skip:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "pipeline"'
    when: never
  mr:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  mr_staging:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME'
  mr_production:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME'
  mr_staging_or_production:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME)'
  mr_not_staging_not_production:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME)'
  mr_not_staging_not_production__manual:
    if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && ($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME)'
    when: manual
    allow_failure: true
  commit_staging:
    if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME'
  commit_production:
    if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME'
  commit_staging_or_production:
    if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $STAGING_BRANCH_NAME || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH_NAME'
  commit_branch_with_open_mr__skip:
    if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
    when: never
```

---

**.gitlab/workflows**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_branch_with_open_mr__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_staging_or_production]
```

---

**.gitlab/stages/test.yml**

```
test-unit:
  stage: test
  needs: []
  tags:
    - test
  script:
    - |
      echo "using SUB_DOMAIN_TEST SUB_DOMAIN_TEST"
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile && yarn test:unit --silent
  coverage: /All\sfiles.*?\s+(\d+.\d+)/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - coverage/
    reports:
      cobertura: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
      junit: reports/junit.xml
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, pipeline__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_staging_or_production]
```

---

.**gitlab/stages/build.yml**

```
.build_default:
  stage: build
  needs: ['test-unit']
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    ...

build-test:
  extends:
    - .build_default
  environment:
    name: test
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_not_staging_not_production]

build-staging:
  extends:
    - .build_default
  environment:
    name: staging
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, pipeline__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_staging]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_staging]

build-production:
  extends:
    - .build_default
  environment:
    name: production
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, pipeline__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_production]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_production]
```

---

**.gitlab/stages/deploy.yml**

```
.deploy-default:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - docker
  interruptible: true
  script:
    ...

deploy-test:
  needs: ['build-test']
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
  environment:
    name: test
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_not_staging_not_production__manual]

deploy-staging:
  needs: ['build-staging']
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
  environment:
    name: staging
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, pipeline__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_staging]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_staging]

deploy-production:
  needs: ['build-production']
  extends:
    - .deploy-default
  environment:
    name: production
  interruptible: false
  rules:
    - !reference [.rule_references, pipeline__skip]
    - !reference [.rule_references, mr_production]
    - !reference [.rule_references, commit_production]
```

Before I applied all those changes my MRs looked as follows:

[image: Merge Request showing detached pipeline above and merge pipeline below]

But after I did all the refactoring my MRs look this way (missing the merge pipeline below the test widget):

[image: Merge Request missing the merge pipeline below]

However, the merge pipeline is created, running, and successful which can be observed in GitLab CI/CD - Pipelines, but it is just not displayed in MRs. Furthermore, when I look into the commit list of master or release branches in GitLab, they are missing the green check icon (pipeline passed) linking to the related pipeline. This also causes the pipeline badge to just show "pipeline unknown".

I suppose that the problem is related to my ruleset, the assignment of the rules to the jobs, and/or the assignment of the rules to workflow. However, I have no clue what to change.

I appreciate you help.

---

**Update:**

I forked the project for trying out some rule changes that might fix the issue. I recognized the issue does not occur in the forked project. I recognized that in the original project the merge commit is not assigned to master but rather to the merge request:

[image: commit assigned to MR]

In contrast in the forked project, the merge commit is assigned to the master branch:

[image: commit assigned to master branch]

There is also a different icon displayed.

Both projects have the same ruleset and I could not find any differences in the settings.

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: i recommend to take a look at the GitLab CI editor for this case, and inspect the merged yaml. maybe you will see there a strange ruleset behaviour for the jobs.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I did that and found the cause. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the issue. The behavior observed above happens only if I have an open merge request (from a feature branch into the master branch) and at the same time another open merge request (from the master branch into the release branch). When the feature branch is now merged into the master branch a pipeline is created and run only for the still open MR (master branch into release branch) and not for the master branch since my rules define “don’t create a pipeline for branches with open MR”. Actually, this behavior is correct because I don’t want duplicate pipelines (as explained in [Worfklow - Switch between branch pipelines and merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines)).

The problem is, however, that my project’s badge (based on master branch) is showing “pipeline unknown” status now, since the pipeline is a merge request pipeline assigned to the open merge request (master branch into release branch) and not a commit pipeline assigned to the merge commit on master.

If I created duplicate pipelines (a merge request pipeline and a branch pipeline), this problem would not occur. However, it remains unclear to me if it is intended by GitLab that I need duplicate pipelines just to get the pipeline badge showing the correct status (passed or failed instead of unknown). Furthermore, I thought it would be great if GitLab would also display an info text that due to the other open MR only a pipeline in the open MR was created, because otherwise if users don’t switch to CI/CD - Pipelines or to the open merge request (master into release), they might be confused and assume that no pipeline runs on merge, as it happened to me.